# Check if remote website is reachable with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I want to check if a remote website is reachable or not, using JavaScript.

```
<button onclick="check()">check</button>

<script>
function check(ip)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var target = "https://letsencrypt.org/"; 
    var rndNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);

    xhr.open('HEAD', target + "?rand=" + rndNum, true);
    xhr.send();

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);

    function processRequest(e)
    {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4)
      {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304)
        {
          alert('up');
        }
        else
        {
          alert('down');
        }
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

This code works, but only for local `target`s, as Cross-Origin Requests are blocked. The code can be executed [here](http://js.do/code/checkurlnoremote) and, when the button is clicked the JavaScript console logs:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://letsencrypt.org/?rand=6236. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).  (unknown)
```

I believe I've read that this is supposed to be working with remote addresses as well somehow.

In general, if the web server answers, I count that as reachable, even `404` return codes tell me that the web server is up and answers, just the specific resource is down.

How can I modify my function, to check the connectivity of remote addresses?

Comment: The remote website you're trying to reach needs to have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` for it to work (or to whitelist your domain only)

Comment: Also, a site isn't down if it returns 4xx code to you

Comment: @Raymond so this function should work, if the remote server has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (or a whitelist)?
@paqash yes, thanks! I need to get that sorted out!

Comment: @Raymond I was able to confirm that. For example with the `target="https://enable-cors.org/"` the function works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that. I'll put it as answer for you to mark as answered and finish the thread.

Comment: @paqash how could I modify the code, so that `alert('up')` is executed if the webserver is reachable else `alert('down')`? Would it be enough to check if `xhr.status !== 0`, instead of `xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make an XML request to a website, make sure that they have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * / or your domain` else it will not work.